# Keyboard covers the whole UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, keyboard, uitextfield, textfield

I am making an iPad app and I have 3 small UIWebViews on the view. I have realized that if there is an HTML input field and I tap on it, Keyboard appears and covers one of the webviews. I can move up the web view but how can I detect which webviews' input field is tapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say use [TapRecognizer](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more) active on the whole view. Using tap recognizer, find the location where it is tapped.

Now based on location I believe you can tell which webview is tapped.

Based on which webview is tapped, you can shift view upside.

Hope this will do the trick.